# Visual studio code tkinter create windows on top

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio code as my IDE for Python 3. When using tkinter, how do I make any newly created windows show on top of visual studio code? Below is the code I'm using.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *

def OpenFile():
    ftypes=[('sqlite files','*.sqlite'),('ALL files','*')]
    return askopenfilename(filetypes=ftypes)

def Main():
    OpenFile()
```

Comment: What happens at the moment when you run the tkinter/python code? Where does the GUI window appear?

Comment: If it creates a new window at all, it gets displayed behind visual  studio  code. Normally with tkinter, I get a window I get a window I can click on, but with the file dialog, I have to move visual studio  code  to my other monitor.

Comment: Can you edit your question to share a short example of code that exhibits this problem?

Comment: Can do! I'll get a simplified version up in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your GUI window variable is root, such that you started tkinter as

`root = Tk()`

The file dialog is a child of the root window by default. So if you make the root window the topmost window on your system, the file dialog will also appear above all other windows on your screen. To do this:

`root.wm_attributes('topmost', True)`

Then, call `OpenFile()`

Comment: That will do it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
root = Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-topmost', True)
```

Thanks @Ron for your solution as hint